# Unable to findout an Url from an output url list

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, fuzzy-search

My code below gives a list of urls.If I want any specific url how to resolve this:
My code is given below:

```
import bs4, requests
index_pages = ('https://www.tripadvisor.in/Hotels-g60763-oa{}-New_York_City_New_York-Hotels.html#ACCOM_OVERVIEW'.format(i) for i in range(0, 180, 30))
urls = []
with requests.session() as s:
    for index in index_pages:
        r = s.get(index)
        soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
        url_list = [i.get('href') for i in soup.select('.property_title')]
        urls.append(url_list)
        print(url_list)
```

Now the output I am getting as a list of Urls.Output is given below:

```
New_York_City_New_York.html', '/Hotel_Review-g60763-d93543-Reviews-Shelburne_NYC_an_Affinia_hotel-New_York_City_New_York.html', '/Hotel_Review-g60763-d1485603-Reviews-Comfort_Inn_Times_Square_West-New_York_City_New_York.html', '/Hotel_Review-g60763-d93340-Reviews-Hotel_Elysee_by_Library_Hotel_Collection-New_York_City_New_York.html', '/Hotel_Review-g60763-d1641016-Reviews-The_Chatwal_A_Luxury_Collection_Hotel_New_York-New_York_City_New_York.html', '/Hotel_Review-g60763-d93585-Reviews-Lowell_Hotel-New_York_City_New_York.html']
D:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py:852: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  InsecureRequestWarning)
['/Hotel_Review-g60763-d277882-Reviews-Hampton_Inn_Manhattan_Seaport_Financial_District-New_York_City_New_York.html', '/Hotel_Review-g60763-d3529145-Reviews-Holiday_Inn_Express_Manhattan_Times_Square_South-New_York_City_New_York.html', '/Hotel_Review-g60763-d208453-Reviews-Hilton_Times_Square-New_York_City_New_York.html', '/Hotel_Review-g60763-d249711-Reviews-The_Hotel_at_Times_Square-New_York_City_New_York.html', '/Hotel_Review-g60763-d1158753-Reviews-Kimpton_Ink48_Hotel-New_York_City_New_York.html', '/Hotel_Review-g60763-d1186070-Reviews-Marriott_Vacation_Club_Pulse_New_York_City-New_York_City_New_York.html', '/Hotel_Review-g60763-d1938661-Reviews-Row_NYC_Hotel-New_York_City_New_York.html', '/Hotel_Review-g60763-d93345-Reviews-Skyline_Hotel-New_York_City_New_York.html', '/Hotel_Review-g60763-d217616-Reviews-Kimpton_Muse_Hotel-New_York_City_New_York.html', '/Hotel_Review-g60763-d1888977-Reviews-The_Pearl_Hotel-New_York_City_New_York.html', '/Hotel_Review-g60763-d223021-Reviews-Club_Quarters_Hotel_Midtown-New_York_City_New_York.html', '/Hotel_Review-g60763-d611947-Reviews-New_York_Hilton_Midtown-New_York_City_New_York.html', '/Hotel_Review-g60763-d4274398-Reviews-Courtyard_New_York_Manhattan_Times_Square_West-New_York_City_New_York.html', '/Hotel_Review-g60763-d1456416-Reviews-The_Dominick_Hotel-New_York_City_New_York.html', '/Hotel_Review-g60763-d122014-Reviews-Gild_Hall_a_Thompson_Hotel-New_York_City_New_York.html', '/Hotel_Review-g60763-d2622936-Reviews-Wyndham_Garden_Chinatown-New_York_City_New_York.html', '/Hotel_Review-g60763-d1456560-Reviews-Kimpton_Hotel_Eventi-New_York_City_New_York.html', '/Hotel_Review-g60763-d249710-Reviews-Morningside_Inn-New_York_City_New_York.html', '/Hotel_Review-g60763-d2079052-Reviews-YOTEL_New_York-New_York_City_New_York.html', '/Hotel_Review-g60763-d224214-Reviews-The_Bryant_Park_Hotel-New_York_City_New_York.html', '/Hotel_Review-g60763-d1785018-Reviews-The_James_New_York_SoHo-New_York_City_New_York.html', '/Hotel_Review-g60763-d247814-Reviews-The_Gatsby_Hotel-New_York_City_New_York.html', '/Hotel_Review-g60763-d112039-Reviews-Hotel_Newton-New_York_City_New_York.html', '/Hotel_Review-g60763-d612263-Reviews-Hotel_Mela-New_York_City_New_York.html', '/Hotel_Review-g60763-d99392-Reviews-Hotel_Metro-New_York_City_New_York.html', '/Hotel_Review-g60763-d4446427-Reviews-Hotel_Boutique_At_Grand_Central-New_York_City_New_York.html', '/Hotel_Review-g60763-d1503474-Reviews-Distrikt_Hotel_New_York_City-New_York_City_New_York.html', '/Hotel_Review-g60763-d93467-Reviews-Gardens_NYC_an_Affinia_hotel-New_York_City_New_York.html', '/Hotel_Review-g60763-d93603-Reviews-The_Pierre_A_Taj_Hotel_New_York-New_York_City_New_York.html', '/Hotel_Review-g60763-d113311-Reviews-The_Peninsula_New_York-New_York_City_New_York.html']
```

Now if I am looking for any particular url from the above list how to do that?
example: For Hilton_Times_Square how to find out the url from the above list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For looking for exact url:

```
def findExactUrl(urlList, searched):
    for url in urllist:
       if url == searched:
           reurn url
```

in Idle you can call

```
>>findExactUrl(url_list, "http://maritonhotel.com/123")
## if such url is in your list
>>"mariton Hotel" 
## or if such url is not there, nothing should show, just:
>>
```

alteranively, calling from your .py file:

```
myUrl = findExactUrl(url_list, "http://maritonhotel.com/123")
print(myUrl)
>>"http://maritonhotel.com/123"
```

You can edit function to return `True` or `i` to find it's index instead.

For more vague search

```
def findOccurence(urlList, searched):
    foundUrls = []
    for url in urllist:
       if url.contains(searched):
           foundUrls.append(url)
    return foundUrls
```

---

if you want to remove some substring from string, simply call .replace() method.

```
for i in range(len(url_list)):
    if "[" in url_list[i]:
        url_list[i] = url_list[i].replace("[", "")
```

---

Let me know if there is something you do not understand. Also, please, seriously consider buying some python book for beginners, or doing some on-line course.

Comment: how to print that url? example: Suppose in my list i have 5 Marriott Hotel.But I need to print only a specific one,then how do I do that?

Comment: >>a = findExactUrl(url_list, "http://MarriottHotel.com/123")< and then you simply call >>print(a)<. Is this clear enough, or should I edit solution?

Comment: @Shaon do you have any more questions?

Comment: Thanks a lot @Kajbo...I just want to add this url : https://www.tripadvisor.in/ with my output..so that it looks like: https://www.tripadvisor.in/Hotel_Review-g60763-d251906-Reviews-The_Wall_Street_Inn-New_York_City_New_York.html...

Comment: I do not understand. Can you elaborate?

Comment: ok..I want to know how do I find any specific hotel url from TripAdvisor from their location(while searching the location name in search box)?

Comment: (https://www.tripadvisor.in['/Hotel_Review-g60763-d208453-Reviews-Hilton_Times_Square-New_York_City_New_York.html']) this is the output I am getting now..But I want to remove [ '  and ' ].Could you please help me to do so?

Comment: The easiest way to do that seems to be using .replace(what, byWhat) method. so you want to do something like myUrl = myUrl.replace("[ '", "").replace("' ]", "")

Comment: you can not do url_list.replace(), because that is list of strings, not one conrete string. What you CAN do, is url_list[i].replace, because that is one concrete string. If those "[ '" marks are in every url adress, run one for loop to destroy it from every string in list.

Comment: @Shaon added to answer

Comment: Thank you..I believe this will help

Comment: @Shaon, It seems like this question is answered, it would be fine if you marked answer you seem like appropriate so you get 2 reputation points. If you have more questions, create new question.

Answer (score 0):

This is what i would do:

```
keyword = "Hilton_Times_Square"
target_urls = [ e for e in url_list if keyword in e ]
```

Comment: How do I print that?

Comment: while I am using print(target_urls) it gives an output show str object is not callable

Comment: To print this you should use a loop: `for u in target_urls: print(u)`

Comment: This is just the same as the "For more vague search" section of Kajbo answers